# Setting time for calendar instance

Tags: java

I'm trying to set time to Calendar instance, but I'm experiencing weird behavior. Let's check some example:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
//c.setTime(date);

c.set(date.getYear(), (date.getMonth() - 1), date.getDay());
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

When I set time with setTime(), it sets wrong date. The second (and deprecated) set(year, month, day) works correctly. I've never met with this before - I thought that it uses default timezone in both cases, so it should be the same. Can someone explain it to me please?

==================== EDIT: Let's ask that another way:

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
c1.setTime(date);

Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();   
c2.set(date.getYear(), (date.getMonth() - 1), date.getDay());

int day1 = c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int day2 = c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

// day1 != day2   ---> I'd like to know - WHY?
```

So for now are dates as follows:

```
date: Nov 5, 2013 4:27:02 PM
day1: 3
day2: 1
time: 1383665222638
timezone: Europe/Prague
```

Comment: To be able to reproduce this: What's the value of `date.getTime()`? Which timezone do you work in?

Comment: Output added to question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line does not do what you think it does:

```
c2.set(date.getYear(), (date.getMonth() - 1), date.getDay());
```

The deprecated methods in the `Date` class work like this:

- `getYear()` returns year - 1900, so that for example 1986 is returned as 86, and 2013 is returned as 113.
- `getMonth()` returns month - 1, so November is returned as 10. Subtracting 1 gives you October.
- `getDay()` returns the day of the week; Tuesday is returned as 2.

So, given your date, you are setting the calendar's date to Oct 2 year 113. The correct use of the API would be:

```
c2.set(1900+date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
```

Comment: It should be from the same timezone - dates are loaded from database (SQLite @ Android), which is filled each day with Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
  today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
  today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
  today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
  today.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

Comment: And does the database contain the correct dates? How do you store the dates (i.e. do you use DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP or ..? Which database system do you use? How do you read the dates back?

Comment: I edited the question - have a look at the new code snippet please - the date is the same in both cases. You can try it on your own - it's not database related.

Comment: It turns out that the problem has nothing to do with time zones and DST this time - see the update.

Comment: It makes sense now! I better read doc more carefully next time :)

Answer (score 4):

Your approach will get a bit hairy especially because of timezones and daylight savings. A lot of the `Date` methods were deprecated because they were confusing to work with.
The approach I like to use is this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());

//get the same day but previous month
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
```

That way I let the `Calendar` do the calculation.

Comment: Getting closer! When I omit the month subtraction, dayOfWeek is returned correctly!!!

Comment: Sorry had a mistake, it had to be `MONTH` for the previous month, not `DAY_OF_MONTH` (copying and pasting bug)

Comment: Thanks, I did it similar to your way, Joni provided explanation, so I chose his answer :). But +1 for your answer too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue in this

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(new Date());

    c.set(2013, (12 - 1), 05);
    int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

If you are trying to do some thing like following will deprecated since you are using Date.

```
  c.set(new Date().getYear(), (new Date().getMonth() - 1), new Date().getDate());
  //don't use `java.util.Date` here since there can be differences
```

`java.util.Calendar` values over `java.util.Date`

Comment: Well, what does your answer in common with my question? :)